# Frustrated with Latest Java Version, Spring Context does not load

Tags: spring, java-8, tomcat8, manifest.mf

Thanks in advance to any one who reads this and can help.

I have an existing code base that I have to update to Java8, it runs in AWS EB. So I am trying to run it under a Java8 + Tomcat8 ami.  When the app starts up, Spring throws an error on init:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   The resource path [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] is not valid

Maven Generated Manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: mgriffith-contractor
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_71
artifactId: quirinus
build-id: 
build-number: 
build-tag: 2.0-${BUILD_NUMBER}
build-time: 2015-03-25_18-40-13
groupId: com.zappos
version: 2.0
```

This error does not show up when the code is compiled and run under Java 7 using Tomcat8.
Google is not being cooperative -- so if you can offer any insights, any/all replies are appreciated.

** Edit ** 
I've also tried setting the target to 1.7. Compiled with Java 8, deployed to a Java8 JVM and Tomcat 8 AMI the entire stack looks like this:

```
25 Mar 2015 22:21:05,473 ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'config' while setting bean property 'location'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] is not valid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:659)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at com.zappos.zommons.web.servlet.DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.doDelayedInit(DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.java:86)
    at com.zappos.zommons.web.servlet.DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.delayedInit(DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.java:79)
    at com.zappos.zommons.web.DelayedInitResourceRegistry.isInitialized(DelayedInitResourceRegistry.java:140)
    at com.zappos.zommons.web.servlet.DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.isInitialized(DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.java:38)
    at com.zappos.zommons.web.servlet.DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.service(DelayedInitHttpServletWrapper.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.zappos.quirinus.filters.JsonpCallbackFilter.doFilter(JsonpCallbackFilter.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] is not valid
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContext.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContextFacade.java:210)
    at com.zappos.zommons.util.VersionUtils.getAttributes(VersionUtils.java:159)
    at com.zappos.zommons.util.VersionUtils.getVersion(VersionUtils.java:122)
    at com.zappos.zommons.spring.ExternalPropertiesResource.getVersion(ExternalPropertiesResource.java:471)
    at com.zappos.zommons.spring.ExternalPropertiesResource.getVersion(ExternalPropertiesResource.java:459)
    at com.zappos.zommons.spring.ExternalPropertiesResource.getVersionedFilename(ExternalPropertiesResource.java:441)
    at com.zappos.zommons.spring.ExternalPropertiesResource.getConfigurations(ExternalPropertiesResource.java:365)
    at com.zappos.zommons.spring.ExternalPropertiesResource.afterPropertiesSet(ExternalPropertiesResource.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Java 8 is supported with at least Spring 4.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that. 3.2.13, which I believe is compatible with Java 8

Comment: I'm afraid it's not, check: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html and also here "Spring Framework 3.2.x will support deployment on JDK 8 runtimes for applications compiled against JDK 7 (with -target 1.7) or earlier. Note that it won’t support JDK 8’s bytecode format (-target 1.8, as needed for lambdas); please upgrade to Spring Framework 4.0 for that purpose.": http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/21/spring-framework-4-0-m1-3-2-3-available/

Comment: My requirement is actually to get the code base compiled under Java 8. Target is set to 1.8 when this happens.  From the 3.2.13 change log: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/changelog.txt

Changes in version 3.2.13 (2014-12-30)
-------------------------------------

fixed Java 8 bridge method handling can lead to false positive detection of autowired annotations (SPR-12187)

Comment: Note that only the latest Spring 4.1.6 released today is compatible with the last Java 8 update 40. See https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/25/spring-framework-4-1-6-released

Comment: Add a slash in front of the path.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that a dependency was trying to read the Manifest file by referencing Jarfile.MANIFEST -- which evidently needs to be

> /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

in Java 8 instead of

> META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

in previous versions...